# Why do Bootstrap tabs have role="presentation"?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on a design system that's extending from the Bootstrap framework. One of the key goals is accessibility. When implementing Bootstrap tabs I see that they apply `role="presentation"` to the list items in their nav list.

So I put together a little chunk of test HTML from the Bootstrap template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

The ARIA spec says that presentation is a role for which:

> The intended use is when an element is used to change the look of the
>   page but does not have all the functional, interactive, or structural
>   relevance implied by the element type,

It seems to me that the `<li>` elements have a structural relevance to someone using an accessibility device as they tell you how many tabs are present. If you were to discover, for example, that the third tab held the information you were interested in, navigating to the list and knowing there are three tabs would let you get to what you want more quickly.

Also, when accessing that test HTML with ChromeVox, the lists are announced identically. So it seems that the `role` doesn't have any practical effect.

I've Googled this question, but haven't found any discussion of it. So, does anyone know why this is part of the Bootstrap framework?

Comment: If you haven't, you might want to check https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/. There is a point there - that you don't want a navigation bar to be announced as a "list of...". Also, with regards to the difference, you might want to drop the hyperlinks and see what happens - the spec. says "role=presentation does not cause the content contained *within the element* to be removed from the accessibility tree."

Comment: I tried a set of links vs. a list in ChromeVox and can hear the difference. I'm not sure which approach users of screen readers would prefer. Without a list, the role seems even less relevant as a span is ignored by ChromeVox in any case. Dropping the hyperlinks loses keyboard accessibility, so that's counter-productive.

Comment: I agree with @theJBRU that this doesn't make sense. With the existence of roles tablist, tab, and tabpane, it seems Bootstrap has decided to do things their own way with a role that is largely misunderstood (because of vague documentation). Bootstrap does use tabpanel, which docs say should be used along with the other 2 roles.

Comment: Fwiw, [all WAI-ARIA roles listed here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions), `presentation` in [draft for 1.1 here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20170628/examples/presentation/PresentationRoleExamples.html), and in [1.0 here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.0/roles#presentation). There's some verbiage that DOM marked `presentation` and below will not be displayed in screen readers, which scares me a little. A little surprised Bootstrap uses it here.

Comment: The `<a>` tags in the example provided are missing their fragment identifiers. Oftentimes `a` tags are cajoled to use `#` in the `href` to put them in focus order but, if the example was copied more or less from Bootstrap documentation, it may be they're using the presentation role to hide the descendent anchors from the accessibility API in order to provide more accessible documentation.

Answer (score 10):

See the write up about accessible tabs by Marco at https://www.marcozehe.de/2013/02/02/advanced-aria-tip-1-tabs-in-web-apps/

His implementation has `role="presentation"` on the li to indicate "that the screen reader should ignore the list items themselves" and then adds the "tab" role on the links "mapping the roles to the intended screen-reader recognizable element type."

One point that was made in an issue in the bootstrap accessibility project (https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin/issues/59) is that (right or wrong) tabs are fairly commonly used as navigation so it would be inappropriate to always include the roles tablist and tab. As Marco's article notes: "There are many circumstances where tabs are not the appropriate semantics."

BTW our job isn't made any easier by the fact that individual combinations of screen readers and browsers fail to support this in the same way. (See this article for a write up on that: http://john.foliot.ca/aria-hidden/)

Answer (score 2):

It is mainly for accessibility purposes. http://john.foliot.ca/aria-hidden/. You can remove or change the "role"

Comment: I get why role=presentation exists, I just don't see why it's being applied by default within the Bootstrap framework. It does not seem to have the intended effect from my tests. I have removed it for now but continue to research.

Answer (score 2):

**`role=presentation` on `<li>` is ONLY needed if there is a `role` on `<ul>` too** e.g. `<ul role="tablist">`.

It's because `<li>` belongs to `<ul>` but not to `<ul role="tablist">`. Such element is not `<ul>` anymore. It's same as `<div role="tablist">` now - its semantics has changed by assigning a `role`. You can run an Accessibility Audit from Chrome Dev Tools and you will get a warning "List items (`<li>`) are not contained within `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent elements." in the given example. It will not be valid.

I hope that clarifies.

#### Do you need `role` at all?

It really depends whether you wanted to implement **actual tabs** (tabs are toggled dynamically by javascript) or a **simple nav** (e.g. standard links that can be bookmarked and/or opened in a new page). Visually both can be styled the same, as tabs, but structurally in case of a simple nav you should not implement any of the roles tablist, tab, tabpanel, presentation etc... Just let them be standard list with links structurally.

#### Arguments to use `role="presentation"` on tablists

- An example from w3.org explains exactly what is going on here (but note that role=tablist is required):
  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#presentation_role
- Last example from the actual ARIA specification https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#presentation
- Blog post by Marco, as mentioned in the answer from @peater https://marcozehe.de/2013/02/02/advanced-aria-tip-1-tabs-in-web-apps/
- Paypal Accessibility plugin implements them too, which is the point how it got into Bootstrap 3.x
  https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin/blob/master/README.md#tab-panel

**Furthermore...**

In Bootstrap 3.4 they still **keep using** `role="presentation"`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tabs-usage

In Bootstrap 4.3 they **decided against using** `role="presentation"` which I personally consider wrong and also it does not pass Accessibility Audit from Chrome Dev Tools
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/