# Bootstrap with role="presentation"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie in web develop and using bootstrap. I am going to create a web page which includes something like Edit tab, Result tab, Setting tab in the navigation bar, and when the user click to one of these tab, only the corresponding view will be displayed, and I want to combine all of them in just one html page. I found in the internet that there is something called: role ="presentation" that can change the presentation but I dont really understand how it works. Is it can be used to navigate from one view to another view, like we navigate from one html page to another html page?.

And if possible, can anyone give me some references/videos or tutorials about how to create such web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31028008/5618881)

Then check out [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) for more about Bootstrap tabs

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <h2>Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    
    <!-- Use class "active" for the first active tab -->
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try role="tablist" instead of presentation.Easily you can combine all tabs(view) in just one html page

Comment: hi shu, do you have example how to use that function?